# Closest pair of points from two sets, one from each

Tags: c#, geometry

I have two sets of points, A and B, and I'm trying to find the closest pair of points where one point is taken from each set. That is, if you were to use the points two draw to lines, I want the two points that allow me to draw the shortest line segment between the two lines.

Looking around, almost everything seems to deal with finding the closest points in 1 set. Although I did find one solution recommending voronoi tesselation to begin with, which seems a bit like overkill, I'm just looking for something a bit nicer than O(n^2).

If it helps, the two sets I'm comparing form lines, although they are not necessarily straight and I'm writing this in C#.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Comment: But that's only for one set of points...

Comment: think about your sentence _"where one point is taken from each set"_ so what do we get? an new set C (A1,B1) or do i miss understand you?

Comment: I mean that of the two points returned from the search, one should be from each of the sets.

Comment: Are  these sets (convex hulls of them) separated?

Comment: They'll likely be seperated, but not in all cases, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to adapt the classical D&C algorithm (as described in the Wikipedia link), by processing all points together and tagging them with an extra bit.

The merging step needs to be modified to accept candidate left-right pairs with a member from every set only. This way, the recursive function will return the closest A-B pair. The O(N.Log(N)) behavior should be preserved.

If the "lines" you mention have a known equation so that point/line distances (or even line/line intersections) can be evaluated quickly, there could be faster solutions.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not quite sure how I'd go about tagging them in C# without adding a fair bit of pre-algorithm work though, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see your point. You can add a boolean variable to your point structure, or maintain a separate list of booleans that parallels the list of points. There's no processing involved.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do this in N log N? I have no idea what to do if all the points from A is clustered tightly near (0, 0), and all the points from B is clustered tightly near, say, (100, 100): I think if that's the case, then "Dividing" then will eventually group all the points from set A together and from set B together, and therefore the merging won't be quick.